# how can i move files through directories in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, file

```
string path = @"C:\Users\peixo\OneDrive\Ambiente de Trabalho\APTIV\moving files\folder";
string destpath = @"C:\Users\peixo\OneDrive\Ambiente de Trabalho\APTIV\moving files\folder1";
    
public Form1()
{
    string[] dele = Directory.GetFiles(destpath);
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        foreach (string rem in dele)
        {
            File.Delete(rem);
        }

        // obter informação dos ficheiros
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);

        // se for a menos de 7 dias vai para...
        if (fi.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7))
        { 
            File.Copy(file, $"{destpath}\\{Path.GetFileName(file)}");
        }
    } ... (more code)
}
```

The point is delete all files before the copy and copy only files that the last time write is 7 days before , but something went wrong and it start copy all files and don't the last write.

Comment: your nested for loops are problems. First delete all files and then copy. So, the for loops will not be nested.

Comment: how can it be correct?

Comment: Your query title is about moving files but code is about copying files. What exactly is your requirement? Copy files or Move files.

Comment: copy, the originals need stay on path

Comment: have you tried? Is it working ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and let me know if you still face issue.

```
public Form1()
{
    string[] dele = Directory.GetFiles(destpath);
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

    foreach (string rem in dele)
    {
       File.Delete(rem);
    }
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        // obter informação dos ficheiros
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);

        // se for a menos de 7 dias vai para...
        if (fi.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7))
        { 
            File.Copy(file, $"{destpath}\\{Path.GetFileName(file)}");
        }
    } ... (more code)
}
```